# Memory leak and swap usage ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, swap, memory-leak

I used to have a LAMP/file headless server, running Ubuntu server 12.04 and 1 GB of RAM. It worked fine, with no problems for years.

When I moved to a new hardware with **4 GB** and server 16.04, serving exactly the same services, my memory gets full with cache and I have a lot of swap usage.

Help me, resolve this isue.

[memory leak screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai7al.png)

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory

*-firmware              
           description: BIOS
           vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
           physical id: 0
           version: P1.30
           date: 05/16/2014
           size: 64KiB
           capacity: 4032KiB
           capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
      *-cache:0
           description: L1 cache
           physical id: 5
           slot: L1-Cache
           size: 128KiB
           capacity: 128KiB
           capabilities: internal write-back unified
           configuration: level=1
      *-cache:1
           description: L2 cache
           physical id: 6
           slot: L2-Cache
           size: 1MiB
           capacity: 1MiB
           capabilities: internal varies data
           configuration: level=2
      *-memory
           description: System Memory
           physical id: a
           slot: System board or motherboard
           size: 4GiB
         *-bank:0
              description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
              product: M378B5673FH0-CH9
              vendor: Samsung
              physical id: 0
              serial: 83047B3B
              slot: A1_DIMM0
              size: 2GiB
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
         *-bank:1
              description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
              product: M378B5773CH0-CH9
              vendor: Samsung
              physical id: 1
              serial: 631A7A4F
              slot: A1_DIMM1
              size: 2GiB
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

Comment: Your screenshot looks kind of normal to me. What are you seeing that's cause for concern?

Comment: With 3 GB free RAM I have 180 MB swap... when my server had only 1GB of RAM the swap was zero. Repeat again, with the same services.

I just clean the swap, and made swapinness=0, and again, for several hours more than 100 MB swap, with NO load at all.

Does not look normal to me at all.

Comment: You running 64-bit Ubuntu server 16.04? How many slots for RAM? How is it populated? show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Yes 64 bit Ubuntu server

Comment: You didn't say how many memory slots you have, and your lshw indicates that it **may** be configured incorrectly. Tell me how many memory slots, and if the actual RAM sockets are colored... ie: some black, some white, or green, etc. And if they **are** colored, which colors contain RAM sticks. Or, if the RAM sockets are numbered J0, J1, J2, etc.

Comment: The motherboiard has two slots, and they are busy with two sticks of RAM

Comment: Well then, you can't have a memory configuration problem. You might check that your BIOS is up to date. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas for you then. Sorry.

Comment: By the way, the RAM I bought shold not be very good, because it is working in single channel mode. It is not a problem for me, because I do not need performance. Could this be connected to swaping?

Comment: Well that's what caught my eye... that it appeared to be working in single-channel mode. But if you've only got two slots... can't be fixed. Check your AMI BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the "swappiness value":
[How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

By the way, you used only 284M, the rest is cache:
[What Does Cached Memory Mean when Viewing htop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327111/what-does-cached-memory-mean-when-viewing-htop)

Comment: Exactly...why the swap then. I tryed with swapinness=0, the same result... still have MBs of swap. And all this with no load.

The new hardware is twice more powerfull than the old one, and has 4 time the RAM, still the swaping is worse.